# cidetector on video from iSight

Tags: face-detection

i am trying to make a basic app to display the video input from iSight and do face detection with CIDetector.

how can I do that?
to use CIDetector, I need CIImage. can I somehow get each frame as CIImage and run the detector on it? and then display the original input, plus some effects I want to add.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

In essence, you use a combination of AVFoundation to capture the frames and Core Image to process those frames using detection.

As a jumping off point, you can start with following this tutorial: http://indieambitions.com/idevblogaday/raw-video-data-app-quick-dirty/

This is an excellent start for getting the EAGLContext, AVCaptureSession and all of the inputs and outputs set up. It also shows how to convert your CMSampleBufferRef into a Core Image which you can then mess with.

To get face detection up and running, you need to add a CIDetector (in this case `@property (nonatomic, strong) CIDetector *faceDetector`) amend the viewDidLoad code with the following:

```
[CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace context:nil options:@{ CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyLow }];
```

One note, you can change the accuracy based on performance.

After that, when you're capturing data, you can gather all of the faces by putting within the `captureOutput:DidOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` function this:

```
    NSArray *featureArray = [self.faceDetector featuresInImage:image];

    for (CIFeature *faceFeature in featureArray) {
        if ([faceFeature.type isEqualToString:CIFeatureTypeFace]) {  //future proof!
            CGRect faceRect = faceFeature.bounds;
            //do whatever you want with faceRect here.
        }
    }
```

Note: this is a way to get it up and running but I've only been able to get it to run at a measly 15 fps on a retina iPad. In the WWDC videos and subsequent source code, they use CIDetector quite efficiently so it can be done.

Good luck!

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same with Metal as it is an improved version of EAGL. But the performance is very bad. Please have a look at my ques: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55062672/ios-cifacedetector-very-slow-with-metal